# How do I fix this syntax error. Validation is the topic

Tags: validation, if-statement, delphi, syntax-error

The program I'm writing should validate a Student ID (String). The ID should be the position of the String[1], [2], and [3] of the ID should be `String[1] = 'c', String[2] = 'f', and String[3] = 'h'`. The ID should begin with 'cfh'. Here is the full button event handler code:

```
procedure Tfrmmain.btnvalClick(Sender: TObject);
var ver: boolean;
    i, buttonSelected: integer;
begin
  ver := true;
  stID := edtID.Text;
  i := length(stID);

  //eRROR code 000
  if edtID.text = '' then begin errormessagelbl.caption := 'Enter a Student ID';
    errormessagelbl.Font.Color := clred;
    edtID.SetFocus;
      {if edtID.SetFocus = true then errormessagelbl.caption := '';}
    exit;
  end;

  //eRROR code 001
  if i <> 13 then begin beep;
    ver := false;
      if not ver then begin errormessagelbl.caption := 'Invalid ID: 001';
        errormessagelbl.Font.Color := clred;
        exit;
      end;

    edtID.text := '';
    edtID.SetFocus;
    exit;
  end;

  //eRROR code 002
  if (stID[1] = 'c') AND (stID[2] = 'f') then begin errormessagelbl.caption := 'Invalid ID: 002'; //focus line
    errormessagelbl.Font.Color := clred;
    exit;
  end;


  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Are you sure that' + '''s correct!',mtConfirmation, mbYESNO, 0);
  if buttonSelected = mrYES then application.Terminate;
  if buttonSelected = mrNO then begin edtID.text := '';
    edtID.SetFocus;
  end;
end;
```

I tried replacing the focus line with `if NOT (stID[1] = 'c') OR (stID[2] = 'f') OR (stID[3] = 'h') then begin errormessagelbl.caption := 'Invalid ID: 002';`.

Comment: Isn't `if (stID[1] <> 'c') OR (stID[2] <> 'f') OR (stID[3] <> 'h') then` what you are looking for? (Cf: You must buy a CAT named ALFRED aged 10. Error: Animal isn't a cat OR name isn't Alfred OR age isn't 10. Equivalently, it is NOT the case that (Animal is cat AND name is Alfred AND age is 10). Congratulations, you have just now understood one of the De Morgan laws!)

Comment: But you also need to learn how to write a clear question, and to choose your tags properly. For instance, this Q has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that?

```
function Validate(AText : string; var AErrorText : string) : integer;
begin
  Result := -1;

  if AText.IsEmpty then
    Result := 0;
  if AText.Length <> 13 then
    Result := 1;
  if not AText.StartsWith('cfh') then
    Result := 2;
  case Result of
    0: AErrorText := 'Enter a Student ID';
    1,2: AErrorText := Format('Invalid ID: 00%d', [Result]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.btnvalClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  errorText: string;
begin
  if Validate(edtID.Text, errorText) >= 0 then begin
    errormessagelbl.Caption := errorText;
    errormessagelbl.Font.Color := clred;
    edtID.SetFocus;
  end else begin
    if MessageDlg('Are you sure that''s correct!',mtConfirmation, mbYESNO, 0) = mrYes then begin
      stID := edtID.Text;
      Application.Terminate
    end else begin
      edtID.text := '';
      edtID.SetFocus;
    end;
  end;
end;
```